# How to convert JSON to XML using Integration Account or Liquid Templates in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, jsonconvert, xmlconvert, liquid-template

Are there any concrete examples where a JSON file is converted to XML using an Integration Account? I specifically want to have influence over the the transformation so a direct @xml(..) is not an option.

Comment: Why not do @xml(..) first and then transform the XML result using an XSL map in the Integration Account?

Comment: @Jay - Is the answer provided was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert JSON to XML as we don't have the Liquid template

[image: Azure]

We need to Create a liquid template and add that to our Integration account.

[Click here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform.md) to get the complete knowledge on Liquid templates and sample codes