# Azure integration account-unable to uplaod json schemas

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

i tried uploading json format data on integration account but it throws an error
"Integration account The content of schema 'sd' of type 'Xml' must be a valid XML."
but on azure logic app i am able to upload json schemas not on azure integration account
If azure integration doesn't support.Kindly help me with the official link

i tried uploading the json file.it not worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-schemas?tabs=consumption), schemas in integration account expects files to be in xsd format and maps to be xslt format.
[image]
If you want to upload json file, you need to use liquid template. Here is reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform?tabs=consumption) to generate liquid templates.
[image]
Basically Integration Account uses maps to transform XML data between formats. A map is an XML document that defines the data in a document that should be transformed into another format.

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977433/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-using-integration-account-or-liquid-templates-in-azur)